# Set flash message after redirect in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am just starting with Angular js. I have a doubt in that. I want to set flash messsage after redirect.

In my case, I have a form and am saving the data through http requst. In the success function I put window.location(). It is another page. I want to set a flash message in that page.

**js**

```
  $scope.Save_Details = function (id)
{  

$http.post(base_url+"sur/sur/save_data/"+id,{data:$scope.Surdata}).
success(function(response) {
   // $scope.successTextAlert = "Saved";  
  //  $scope.showSuccessAlert = true; 

    window.location = "#/surpage/nextpage?show_message= true";
});
}
```

**new update**

```
 var messageFlag = $location.search().show_message;
    if(messageFlag && messageFlag === 'true'){ 
    alert(messageFlag);
        $scope.successTextAlert = "Saved";  
        $scope.showSuccessAlertMsg = true; 
    }
```

**view**

```
  <div class="alert alert-success" ng-show="showSuccessAlert">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-ng-click="switchBool('showSuccessAlert')">×</button> <strong> {{successTextAlert}}</strong>
        </div>
```

Anyone help me?

Comment: pass a query string/route data flag to the other page, read the flag and display flash message accordingly

Comment: I'm not clear about that.Can u explain ..?

Comment: 1. When you navigate to "nextpage" pass a flag along -> #/surpage/nextpage?show_message= true
2. In the "nextpage" controller, read the query string value for "show_message" ($location.search().show_message), if  that value == true, show your flash message

Comment: can u please add this as answer with sample code.i think this exactly i want

Comment: is it working or are you facing any issue? I have added this as answer, please comment on it if you need more info. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Put this code in HTML -

```
<!-- message text     -->
<div class=" panel-{{alerts.class}}" ng-show="alerts.messages" >
    <div ng-repeat="alert in alerts.messages track by $index" class="panel-body alert-{{alerts.class}}" >{{alert}}</div>
</div>
```

Put this code in angular model -

```
$rootScope.alert = function(type,msg){
        $rootScope.message.push(msg);
        $rootScope.alerts = {
            class: type,
            messages:$rootScope.message
        }
    }
```

For success message -

```
$rootScope.alert('success',"Success !!!");
```

For Error message -

```
$rootScope.alert('danger',"Error.");
```

Comment: type = Is it error message or success and in message what message you want to display.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT - Adding code**

```
yourAppModule.controller('nextPageController', function($location){

   var messageFlag = $location.search().show_message;
   if(messageFlag && messageFlag === 'true'){
     //show your message
   } 

});
```

- When you navigate to "nextpage" pass a flag along ->   #/surpage/nextpage?show_message= true
- In the "nextpage" controller, read the query string value for
  "show_message" *( inject $location to your controller and get value
  using $location.search().show_message)*
- if that value == true, show your flash message

Comment: Please add code for this..i'confused ($location.search().show_message)

Comment: @user6721756 - inject $location to your controller. $location.search() returns an object of query string values.

Comment: value= $location.search().show_message ; 
  if(value==true)
  {
       $scope.successTextAlert = "Saved";  
            $scope.showSuccessAlertMsg = true; 
  }

Comment: how does your url looks like when it is navigated to "nextpage"?

Comment: @user6721756 - try if(value === 'true')

Comment: are you getting any value for $location.search().show_message? try alert($location.search().show_message);

Comment: @user6721756 - please try alerting the value and let me know. Comment the issue you are facing once you are back.

Comment: @user6721756 - Could you post your controller code?

Comment: instead of window.location = "#/surpage/nextpage"; try window.location = "#/surpage/nextpage?show_message=true'";  or $location.path('/surpage/nextpage?show_message=true')

Comment: alert is working outside the AppModule.Now i put the set of code inside this AppModule

Answer (score 0):

You can use toastr JS specially for flash.
http://codeseven.github.io/toastr/demo.html

By using below js code, you can display a flash message.

**For success message :** 
toastr"success";

**For Error message :**
toastr"success";